# How do you manage Monster Crystals with Infusion?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

So I now have a nice collection of monsters, even managed to tame a Behemoth last night *g*, but I'm curious how the system works.

I know you can use Feral Link to kill monsters and this gives you a better chance of capturing them. "Gotta catch em all!" so once you've got them you can level them up.

The main thing is the Infusion system. I've no idea which monsters are better than others? So far I've stuck with the same ones the whole time and levelled them up, my RAV monster is lv30 something. I notice at these higher levels they get more inherant abilities which you can infuse to other monsters.

Am I right in guessing that you have to level up a low monster, then switch to a higher level one, infuse the lower one into the better on and then go recapture it? So far I've been sorting my monsters using [triangle] and sorting by strength and magic, and just going on which has the best stats.

Any clues would be ace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to Infuse; one good example would be Chichu.  You can make this monster into a really powerful COM monster.  You can also power up Chocobos so you win more racing matches.

Here are 2 videos for the two examples above:

Chocobo -

Chichu -

Be sure to read the video description for more information.